# How to perfectly center a character in a box with DrawRectangle and DrawString..?

Tags: vb.net

Given the following VB.Net code sample, how can the characters be drawn in the boxes with perfect vertical centering..? If one looks closely, some are not vertically centered, and have a tiny vertical offset.

[image]

LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center is already specified, but it's not perfect. Perhaps there are font or display properties that can be used to calculate the slight adjustment that is needed? If not in .Net, then perhaps in Windows API calls?

In this line of the code, an offset is applied, but it was determined by experimentation. I would like to find a more precise calculation.

```
p.Offset(0, fontSize * 0.1)
```

I checked the .Net Font class, but I didn't see any native properties that could be used as described. But then, I might not be understanding what's right in front of me. I also Googled for an answer, but got too much information.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim fontSize As Integer = 24
    Dim boxSize = 30
    DrawTargetBox(g, New Point(40, 40), boxSize, "X", "Arial", fontSize)
    DrawTargetBox(g, New Point(80, 40), boxSize, "X", "Times New Roman", fontSize)
    DrawTargetBox(g, New Point(120, 40), boxSize, "X", "Courier New", fontSize)
    DrawTargetBox(g, New Point(160, 40), boxSize, "X", "Calibri", fontSize)
    DrawTargetBox(g, New Point(200, 40), boxSize, "X", "Tahoma", fontSize)
    DrawTargetBox(g, New Point(240, 40), boxSize, "X", "Comic Sans", fontSize)
End Sub

Private Sub DrawTargetBox(g As Graphics, p As Point, boxSize As Integer, boxLabelText As String, fontName As String, fontSize As Integer)
    g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.0), New Rectangle(p.X - (boxSize / 2), p.Y - (boxSize / 2), boxSize, boxSize))
    Dim textVerticalOffset = (boxSize / -2) - (fontSize)
    p.Offset(0, fontSize * 0.1) 'vertical squidge to hit the center of the point/box
    Dim strFormat As New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip)
    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    g.DrawString(boxLabelText, New Font(fontName, fontSize), Brushes.Black, p, strFormat)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You are not measuring how much space each char in each font requires.  `Graphics.MeasureString` is one way `TextRenderer.MeasureText` is another

Comment: I just tried both code samples provided for those properties at MSDN, but they didn't work. MeasureText seems to be used simply as an intermediary type to calculate the font size. MeasureString didn't work; on my display the "M" is not vertically centered in the box.

Comment: I think I need something that looks into the font design and says, "the baseline of this font is positioned N percent of the distance from [something]". I do realize I may be describing font characteristics incorrectly.

Comment: I get 5 different sizes for those fonts.  there is not a lot of difference between 39.74999 and 43.06249 but neither is there a huge difference in the spacing shown.

Comment: Ok, sorry to be dense, but could you tell me how you did that so I can understand, and determine if I can apply it to my issue?

Comment: You would probably be happier if you used Ẍ instead of X.  [More here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b(v=vs.110).aspx).